# D3 V4 - Canvas Transitions: d3.timer duration

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, d3.js

I followed the [example here](http://bl.ocks.org/JMStewart/e6efab7dc6ca09702adb) regarding transitions with canvas elements.
Since i am using d3 version 4.2.2 i tried to port the example without success.
The problem is that (depending on the `d3.timer` duration) the animation stops at a point, where the dots are not at their proper position. It works fine with *d3 v3*. Here is a portion of the code:

```
var duration = 1000;
var delay = function(d) {
  return d.i;
}
var maxDelay = 0;
var timeScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, duration])
  .range([0, 1]);

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.trans = {
    i: d3.interpolateNumber(height, d.y),
    delay: delay(d)
  };
  if (d.trans.delay > maxDelay) {
    maxDelay = d.trans.delay;
  }
});

var renderTime = 0;
var timer = d3.timer(moveCircles);

function moveCircles(t) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var time = timeScale(t - d.trans.delay);
    d.y = d.trans.i(time);
  });
  var start = new Date();
  drawCircles('black');
  var end = new Date();
  renderTime += (end - start);
  if (t >= duration + maxDelay) {
    console.log('Render time:', renderTime);
    timer.stop();
    return true;
  }
}
```

[See this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xCXSm24oHFT1segwGMRu?p=preview) for a full example. The red dots are indicating the proper position (x/y) of the data. So, every black dot should overlap with one red dot. The higher the y value of the dot, the higher the distance to its proper position. This lead me to the assumption that there is an error in the interpolation of the y value ?

Is there a way to set a duration (e.g. 1000) and to animate the dots s.t. each dot is at its proper position after the specified duration ?

**EDIT:** It turned out that using the same `easeCubicInOut` as in the provided example it works fine. I don't know why this works.

```
var ease = d3.easeCubicInOut;
...
function moveCircles(t) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    //var time = timeScale(t - d.trans.delay); // without the ease it won't work
    var time = ease(timeScale(t - d.trans.delay));
    d.y = d.trans.i(time);
  });
...
```

How can i skip the ease ?

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer as I'm not following all the calculations but there's something up with the math here:

```
var time = timeScale(t - d.trans.delay);
d.y = d.trans.i(time);
```

`t - d.trans.delay` needs to produce a value between 0 and 1000 so that it'll scale between 0 to 1.  Obviously you are feeding your `interpolate` functions values greater then 1.  I believe this:

```
if (t >= duration + maxDelay) {
```

is the culprit as you are going to run the animation past 1000 milliseconds.

A naive approach would be to just cap it:

```
var time = timeScale(t - d.trans.delay);
if (time > 1) time = 1;
d.y = d.trans.i(time);
```

That said, I'm not sure this code needs to be so complex.  A basic [transition](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition) should be able to do what you are after:

```
d3.select({})
  .transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .tween("animate.circles", function() {
    return function(t) {
      data.forEach(function(d,i){
        d.y = d.trans.i(t);
      });
      drawCircles('black');
    };
});
```

Updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jBM3BvOYtb2QKnVnIMyP?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I totally aggree with you and your plunker works great ! The problem is that afaik transition is not scalable with respect to the number of data points (or is there a workaround ?), which was basically one of my intentions to use also a canvas instead of a svg. If you e.g. change  `size = 10000`, the transition is not smooth anymore.